# I can't delete my account picture

Tags: user-accounts, microsoft-surface-pro

I just got my Microsoft surface pro 3, and I put up a picture as my account picture...when I changed it it was still available for anyone too see. How can I delete my account picture rather than change it?

Answer (score 1):

Open the file explorer and set the view options to show hidden files. Go to:

C:\Users\"your user name"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\AccountPictures

Delete the pictures you don't want anymore showing in your account picture selection.

Answer (score 0):

[There is no option in windows 8 to remove the account picture](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/remove-account-picture/8f1468f9-780c-4da6-8420-0818ad5f2565).

Alternatively, you can open microsoft paint, then save a blank.jpg or blank.png and set either one as logon screen. (blank white space)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a  way to delete it, but you can change it manually back to the default. You will need to set Windows Explorer to view hidden items.

[image]

Go into Windows Explorer and navigate to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Default Account Pictures` then copy one of the default pictures to your desktop.

Close Explorer and go to change your Account Picture. Browse to your desktop and select the default picture.

*Note: this is for Windows 8.  Not exactly sure what the directory structure is on a Surface.*

Answer (score -1):

For a Microsoft Surface Pro device, go to:

```
C:\Users\name.name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Account Pictures
```

There they are.